# Spring Boot project shows the Login page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a `Spring boot` project with the `Spring initializer` and only have the starter code so far.

The sample code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I expect it to return the `index.html` page from the `templates` folder. Instead, I'm redirected to the `http://localhost:8080/login` address and asked for the username/ password. In the `application.properties` file, I tried to use the configuration of,

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=Bootstrap Spring Boot
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true 
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bootapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=testpassword
server.error.path=/error
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

I tried to login with the username `testuser` and the password `testpassword`. This doesn't work out.

I use the following `pom.xml` in the project,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.online.books</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Ecommerce</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is the default behavior. to change this, you have a few options:

You can remove the Spring Boot Security dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can disable autoconfiguration. To do so; in your main class, to: `@SpringBootApplication` append: `(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` so that it looks like:

```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecurityApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

you can also do this from the application.properties file

For more information on desableing Auto-Configuration and setting up your own. Reference:
[Spring Boot Security Auto-Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration)

Comment: This doesnt work at least at latest spring version 5.3.9 and java verionn 11

Comment: I use spring boot 3.0.2. Removing the Spring Boot Security dependency does not work but append `exclude` do work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 147):

If you don't want login page (from `Spring-Security`) remove the following dependency from your `pom.xml` and do `maven` update to refresh the dependencies on the class path.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or if you want to use the `Spring-Security` then on `console` it will display the default password like below :

```
Using default security password: ce6c3d39-8f20-4a41-8e01-803166bb99b6
```

the default username will be `user`

Comment: How to disable default security?

Comment: Many people put the Spring security dependency in the pom even if they actually dont intend to use it.

Comment: "default username will be user"  Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!  Thanks for info.

Comment: I removed but no luck, im using gradle and `compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'` used

Comment: Is there a reason it includes default view of the login page?

Comment: @wonsuc yes, It's from `SpringBoot-AutoConfiguration`

Comment: Because I'm using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode my user password, is there a way to keep using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` but not showing the login page??

Comment: I removed "spring-boot-starter-security". It still showing login page.

Answer (score 10):

When you include ***spring-boot-starter-security*** then the login page will automatically be shown.

To remove this login page-

1. If you use **Maven** then removing this dependency and rebuild the project. Already there are some answers for this. Just remove the block (pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. If anyone uses **Gradle** then, just remove the following block from **dependencies** block(build.gradle) and reload build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    ...
}
```

3. If you do not want to change the config file like pom.xml or build.gradle then source code level change will be the best suit for you. To do this, need to update the main class with, change **@SpringBootApplication** annotation with **@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})**. This excludes parameter will remove **Security** configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringCacheApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

4. Moreover, if you want to keep the login page, then you can log in with **generated security password**. You can find it into **console**, looks like:
   **Using generated security password:** ***d408ce6f-470d-4**4-950a-81**9651f321***

```
{
"usename" : "user",
"password": "d408ce6f-470d-4**4-950a-81**9651f32"
}
```

For more information, you can read [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/boot-features-security.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can add a class in your Project,
for Web Security configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Comment: I add it to the main class and worked perfectly, thanks!!!

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found

Answer (score 4):

[Check the console to find the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZEXM.png)

Also as a username please use "user" as a credential.

If you want to disable that spring functionality, go to your pom xml and delete the dependency below;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code without the starter-security but still ask for login.

Here is the solution:

disable your autoconfiguration in main class,

@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: One of the previous answers already contains this information. Does this answer add anything new to the discussion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the spring security and you've defined the WebSecurityConfig then make sure you have these two annotations on your WebSecurityConfig class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

Answer (score 0):

if you have login page displayed; it means that security is activated;
you comment or delete those dependencies from pom.xml:

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

or:

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

or:

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case it was because of missing @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity annotations in SecurityConfig file

Comment: Since the questioner doesn't show any security config I think this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue due to scan packages is not mentioned appropriate package against annotation `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ="<<incorrect_package_structure>>")`

Answer (score -1):

if you really want to disable this login page you may disable your class where is:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

this class is not necessary
in my opinion you haven't create this class whose extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.